# Virtual Threads pool with Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

## Application

I just updated to spring-boot 3.2.0.

My application is using spring-kafka and starts a lot of kafka consumers dynamically.

## Problem

When I set : `spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true`, I get the following error in
`org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer` :

```
    
Consumer thread failed to start - does the configured task executor have enough threads to support all containers and concurrency?
```

When I disable virtual threads, its working like before.

## Question

Why ? Is there a limitation in the virtual thread pool ? Should I (and how) customize it ?

Thanks

## Edit 1

It seems to be related to synchronized.

I'm using a synchronized block inside which I'm creating a KafkaListener and starting it.
The start hangs, and after some time, this message is displayed.

Comment: Sounds like similar to this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38563. Would you mind to raise a GH issue for https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka with some simple project to let us to reproduce on our side?

Comment: Created a github issue : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2933

Comment: `synchronized` and virtual threads can be problematic and lead to pinning. You should use a lock instead. That being said you might also be running into another issue.

Comment: But I thought VT are fully compatible and syncrhonized could only lead to reducing benefits of VT ?